# How to access a method from another Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now, I have a controller called `Reports` and inside of it I have a method called `generate_pdf`. When the user clicks the PDF icon, it routes to `generate_pdf`. Works fine.

However, now I am running a background task that needs to access the same code within `generate_pdf` from the `Report` controller.

How can I accomplish this? A redirect will not work because, again, it's a background process. Should I relocate this code elsewhere and just source it from there, or can I somehow just call the `Report` controller and past parameters? The end result of `generate_pdf` is rendering content to the user's web browser, but since this is a background task, I'm assuming it'll just return the content to whatever called it.

Comment: If `generate_pdf` is referenced from the `Reports` controller and from a background task, then perhaps a good place for it is in `lib`. Where is the background task defined?  Your comment that you need the background task "to access the same code within generate_pdf from the `Report` controller." Is a little confusing. Do you mean the background task accesses the `Report` controller which, in turn, calls `generate_pdf`? Is `Report` different than `Reports`? If `generate_pdf` is only referenced from multiple controllers, then `app/controllers/concerns` would be a good place for it.

Comment: Hi @lurker Yes, I need the background task (a sidekiq worker) to access the `generate_pdf` method within the `Reports` controller. Sorry for the mixup between 'Reports' and 'Report' as well. it is just a single controller with a generate_pdf method that needs to be accessed by the user via the UI (just with a normal route that works properly) as well as a from sidekiq background worker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably a couple of ways of doing this. But one way would be to define `generate_pdf` in a lib file such as `lib/pdf_tools/generate_pdf.rb`. It would look something like:

```
module PdfTools
  def generate_pdf
    ...
  end

  ... # Other methods that support generate_pdf if needed
end
```

Then create a file `config/initializers/pdf_tools.rb` which contains:

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/lib/pdf_tools/*.rb").each do |file_name|
  require file_name
end
```

You can structure this in various ways to your liking. Rails will run the initializers automatically when the application starts. Creating the appropriate initializer should ensure that it is included in your controller and your background task.

Answer (score 1):

You should stay away from trying to use a controller action inside a background job or any other Rails class.
That's not a good pratice.

In my opinion, a possible approach to solve this problem, would be to create a class `ReportService` (or something like that) and define there the `generate_pdf` method.
This method would contain the common code should be shared between the controller and the background job.
For instance, the render part of the content should still be done only in the controller.

```
# app/services/report_service.rb
class ReportService
  def generate_pdf
    # Inside here should be the common logic for the PDF generation
    # The result should in a suitable format in order to be able to be used by the controller and by the background job
  end
end
```